# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch - Periodogram MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following code on MATLAB:

```
N = [64 128 256 512];
NumOfRuns = 50;   
PerLength = 2048;  
freq = 0:2/(PerLength-1):2;
for m=1:length(N)
    Px = zeros(NumOfRuns,PerLength);
    for i=1:NumOfRuns
        x = randn(1,N(m));
        Px(:,i) = periodogram(x);
    end
end
```

When I run this code on MATLAB, it gives the error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. 
>   Error in exampl13(line 10) Px(:,I)=periodogram(x).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313016/subscripted-assignment-dimension-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

**Code Notes:**

```
N = [64 128 256 512];
NumOfRuns = 50;   
PerLength = 2048; 

% freq = 0:2/(PerLength-1):2; % you are not using freq

% You are looping from 1:4, defining Px each time, not storing Px outside of the loop. 
% After this loop, Px will just be in its 4th state. 
for m = 1:length(N)

    Px = zeros(NumOfRuns,PerLength);

    for i = 1:NumOfRuns 

        x = randn(1,N(m));
        Px(:,i) = periodogram(x);

    end

end
```

**Periodogram:**

You're assuming `periodogram` returns the same number of elements as are input to it. A simple test will tell you that is not true!

```
a = periodogram([1, 2]);
numel(a)
% >> ans = 129
```

Read the documentation here:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html

> The number of points, nfft, in the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is the maximum of 256 or the next power of two greater than the signal length

So above, the `129` is related to `2^7 = 128`

Try using `pxx = periodogram(x,window,nfft)`

Comment: Thank you for your helpful idea. It works for a single plot. But I want the following: 1. Storing PX and getting 50 ensemble plots. I left putting the code here for plotting the ensembles, because I am OK with that.